# Python CNN image classification model fails to classify individual images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am very new to machine learning. Looking at other work, I trained the following model
https://www.kaggle.com/code/konstansan/cat-and-flower-image-classifier,
which shows very high accuracy (98 - 99%) based on calculations for the testing set. To run the notebook, one needs a Kaggle account.

However, most often the model fails to classify accurately individual images from the testing set.
I have 2 categories, 10 000 images per category in the training set, 2000 per category in the validation set, and 50 per category in the testing set. The images in the 3 sets are not too different in terms of size, contents, etc.

I then trained a similar model which had about 85% accuracy but still fails on individual images.

Could someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like model accuracy is good on the training set but not really working on the testing set.

It might be because of any of the below reasons:

- Because of the algorithm
- Because of hyper parameters
- Because of data overfitting
- Because the data might not be good

Comment: Thank you, Myra. On the testing set, it calculates the prediction accuracy score correctly so it seems it works there a bit. I will try with a completely different model architecture (I tried with similar one, which produced the same issue). I will try training with 50 epochs (currently 25). As far as I know, overfitting mostly occurs when there are not enough training images, I have 20000. The testing data is similar to the training data.